# Sql Server Agent notification email  with custom message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have set email notification on the completition of a scheduled job.

Is it possible to customize the email content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is added a final step to the job, then I can use Database Mail to customize everything about the message (subject, body, recipients, from, etc) based on the server, the status/outcome of the job, and even the duration.

It is cumbersome if you have a lot of jobs, but I did this for a variety of other reasons as well (for example, other actions to perform in addition to sending an e-mail).

You may also consider a management tool like [SQL Sentry](https://www.sentryone.com/products/sentryone-platform/sql-sentry/sql-server-performance-monitoring) which provides lots of flexibility over how to handle successful/failed jobs, and has comprehensive options for subsequent actions.

Comment: I don't understand.  How does adding a final step to the job allow me to use Database Mail to customize the message?  Perhaps you mean to write code in the final step the executes EXEC sp_send_dbmail in which we can customize the message.  That makes sense.

Comment: @Baodad Because you can call sp_send_dbmail yourself, with whatever subject, body etc. as you want *as a part of that job step* instead of relying on the default alerting mechanisms Agent will do. You can even have multiple steps that do this, so that if step 1 fails, it calls step 7, which e-mails the people who care if step 1 fails. If step 1 succeeds it moves to step 2, and maybe that notification list is different, so step 2 on failure calls step 8, which has a *different* call to sp_send_dbmail. 7 and 8 wouldn't be reached on their own except through failure of a prior step.

Answer (score -1):

Using the native tools, no.  You'd need to use the method that Aaron talks about.